# Invite Friends through gmail and track who all have been invited

Tags: google-contacts-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I feel my question is new, however, in case this question is repetitive, my apologies in advance. Thanks for genius guys here and helping the entire IT ecosystem.

problem: I am building one app, where enabling the feature of an invite to friends through emails. Invite friend feature is available through google API contacts, however, my requirement is to match the invited friends with the friends who really registered to the site.

e.g. MailID a@a.com invited 100 friends of which only 10 registered in the site.
So A will be credited with 10.
 Mailed b@b.com invited 200 friends of which 200 registered in the site. So B will be credited with 200.

Like this whoever has more numbers at the end of promotions, will be awarded some prize.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use the Google API Contacts (directly or using any friendly wrapper, like [GData](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client) or [CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/), tell me which language are you working with it) to import friends contacts to your invitation form.

The you'll need to build the **email sending** (or any invitation sending mechanism) and **invitation tracker** by yourself.

Or use which people calls [Referral Marketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referral_marketing) tools.

Comment: You can take a look for GData for PHP: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib